# esbuild fails due to missing android-arm when running on ubuntu x86-64 on GitHub actions

Tags: node.js, npm, serverless-framework, esbuild

I have a node 14 AWS lambda function using `serverless-bundle` for packaging, which in turn uses `esbuild`. Installing it locally works fine both with `npm install` and `npm ci`, also when deleting `node_modules`.
This code is supposed to run on AWS Lambda standard x86-64 containers.
To deploy it, I've set up a pretty straight forward GitHub actions workflow

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node.js 14.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install
        run: npm ci
```

However, the `install` step fails immediately with:

```
Run npm ci
npm ERR! @esbuild/android-arm not accessible from esbuild
```

I don't understand what on Earth is going on here. Sure, package-lock.json could be influenced by the fact that it was produced on my Mac M1 as it has an `@esbuild/darwin-arm64` entry, but:

1. Why would `ubuntu-latest` on GHA need `android-arm` binaries?
2. If the problem is that `package-lock.json` is produced on one architecture and then used to install on another, how should I go about to produce `package-lock.json` in the first place? I don't want to run my entire dev env dockerized ... :(

The only threads I found about this are slightly similar issues like [this](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2202), and the advice is then to upgrade to Node 16 (without any explanation as to why it would help). I could do that, but it would make my environment very messy, having different nvm configs for different components within my solution, so I'd rather not (especially not when I don't understand *why* it would help).

I did see that my `package-lock.json` contains this:

```
    "esbuild": {
      "version": "0.16.17",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esbuild/-/esbuild-0.16.17.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-G8LEkV0XzDMNwXKgM0Jwu3nY3lSTwSGY6XbxM9cr9+s0T/qSV1q1JVPBGzm3dcjhCic9+emZDmMffkwgPeOeLg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@esbuild/android-arm": "0.16.17",
        "@esbuild/android-arm64": "0.16.17",
        "@esbuild/android-x64": "0.16.17",
        "@esbuild/darwin-arm64": "0.16.17",
```

However, `esbuild`:s `package.json` lists these as `optionalDependencies`:

```
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@esbuild/android-arm": "0.16.17",
    "@esbuild/android-arm64": "0.16.17",
    "@esbuild/android-x64": "0.16.17",
    "@esbuild/darwin-arm64": "0.16.17",
    "@esbuild/darwin-x64": "0.16.17",
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was related to my `npm` version. I had 7.24.2 locally but on GHA I got 6.x due to that being the default `npm` version in Node 14. Possibly this is related to a difference in how `optionalDependencies` are handled.

The solution was to add a step that upgrades `npm` on GHA:

```
      - name: Upgrade npm
        run: npm install -g npm@7
```

There's a [request](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/213) on `actions/setup-node` to support `npm_version` but for now it's not supported and the suggested workaround is the above.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the node version used in the jenkins file in the project.

```
withEnv(["PATH+NODE=${tool 'nodejs14.18'}/bin"]) {
 //your jenkins code goes here
}
```

so if you go to jenkins -> `Global Tool Configuration -> NodeJS installations`, you can see all your node versions used for different projects. The name which we give for the node version(it can be anything) is used in our jenkins files. Below name you can see the node version. Locally I was using node `16.4` and on jenkins it was `14.8`. Issue pop up once I delete and recreate the `package-lock.json` file after updating some packages.